# jQuery Validate, trying to copy a demo, can't figure out how they are doing it

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, requiredfieldvalidator

So I was reading through [this page](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation) because I want to add validation to own form, before I am converting the answers to fill in a PDF and email, and I was looking at the example [here](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/marketo/), but I can't find out for the life of me how they actually have their fields marked as "required". In comparing the address field and the second field I see that they use the word required in the class selection, but how do they use that as the identifier for what fields are required or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"...but I can't find out for the life of me how they actually have their fields marked as `required`"*

They have `class="required"` inline with the HTML markup...

```
<input class="required" ...
```

**Quote OP:**

> *"...I see that they use the word required in the `class` selection, but how do they use that as the identifier for what fields are required or not?"*

*That's exactly how*... by using `class="required"`.

This is only one way that rules can be declared for this plugin.  Generally, rules that are normally declared with a `true` (*within the `.validate()` method*), can instead be placed within the `class` attribute, such as `required`, `digits`, `email`, etc.  However, rules that take more complex parameters, such as `max`, `maxlength`, `min`, etc. cannot be declared in this fashion.

This plugin will also recognized HTML5 validation attributes...

```
<input required="required" ...
```

Comment: ok, well as far as I know class refers to the stylesheet, but their only use of the word "required" in the css is: tr.required which does to relate to the fields that are required, correct? so why would you use class="required" compared to required="required"

Comment: @Radish, it's perfectly acceptable to have `class` names in your HTML markup that are not referenced in your CSS.  It's a commonly accepted practice when using jQuery plugins to use dedicated `class` names to aid in selecting certain DOM elements.  As far as why you'd use `class` names instead of HTML5 validation attributes in this case:  personal preference, `doctype`, and project specifications.  However, I prefer to keep everything totally separate and only declare my validation rules within the `.validate()` method; whenever possible and practical.